# Php-Problems with getting the value of radio input using model-view-controller pattern

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to do get the value of a group of radio inputs in a form but it doesn't work.

VIEW:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="Index.php?opt=filter">
stuff...
.
.
.
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="categoria"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-0">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-0" value="Aseo" checked="checked" type="radio" disabled>
          Aseo
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-1">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-1" value="Botiquín" type="radio" disabled>
          Botiquín
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-2">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-2" value="Cacharrería" type="radio" disabled>
          Cacharrería
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-3">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-3" value="Cafetería" type="radio" disabled>
          Cafetería
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-4">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-4" value="Cristalería" type="radio" disabled>
          Cristalería
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-5">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-5" value="papeleria" type="radio" disabled>
          Papelería
        </label>
        </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="categoria-6">
          <input name="categoria" id="categoria-6" value="Tecnología" type="radio" disabled>
          Tecnología
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
</form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function filter(){    
        $Arreglo = array();
        if(isset($_POST['categoria']))
        {
            $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
            $Arreglo = array("categoria"=> $categoria);
        }
        print_r($Arreglo);
        return $this->model->filterTable($Arreglo);
}
```

MODEL:

```
class ContactoModel extends DB {
    const FILTER_MESSAGEC = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE category=?";
    .
    .
    .
    public function filterTable($filterRecord){
        $this->open_connection ();
        if (key($filterRecord)=="categoria") {
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare ( self::FILTER_MESSAGEC );
            $statement->bind_param ("s", $filterRecord["categoria"]);
        }
        $sucess = $statement->execute();
        $result = "Fail";
        if (! $sucess) {
            throw new Exception ( 'Lo sentimos ha ocurrido un error contacte al administrador' );
        }
        else{
            $result= $statement->get_result();
        }
        $statement->close ();
        $this->close_connection ();
        return $result;
    }
```

Image1: [Result (wrong!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtqDb.png)

I know that the logic is ok, because with another type input like `textarea`, it works! But I don't know what happen with `radio` input type and I've been trying and searching but I can't get it. :(

Image2: [Result (good!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol6rr.png)

Obviously, I have entries with `papeleria` in the field category.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit `disabled` inputs. Therefore, remove the attribute `disabled` on all of your radio buttons.

**Edit:**

Give your 3 check-buttons a class name e.g. `btn-filter` and use the code below. I think it should work with your current HTML structure.

```
$('.btn-filter').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // cache the elements you need
  var $btn = $(this),
      // cache the inputs (input, textarea, button, select) excluding .btn-filter button
      // within the column
      $inputs = $btn.closest('[class^=col]').find(':input:not(.btn-filter)');
  // de-activate button and disable his sibling inputs
  if ($btn.hasClass('active')) {
      $btn.removeClass('active');
      $inputs.prop('disabled', true);
  // activate button and enable his sibling inputs
  } else {
      $btn.addClass('active');
      $inputs.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaqBQj?editors=1010).

Comment: Great! It works. However, I had the `disabled` tag because I want to remove it through jQuery. As you see in the images, I have three checkbuttons: "Categoría", "Precios" and "Descripción". Therefore, the idea is, whether you want filter records with one of these, so checked it or check two or check the three. But when I try to use jQuery, the filter doesn't work. Do you understand? I attach two images about what I'm doing [https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wu8s6bdcpk71f3/CategoryButton.png?dl=0] and [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayrs2e19hja1qxu/jQueryCateButton.png?dl=0]

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you want enable/disable input elements in a column depending on whether the related checkbox is on/off. If so, look at my edit above.